# Process running on cuda terminated, nothing logged

Tags: process, gpu

I had a process running on CUDA on a remote server, and at some point, it was terminated, without logging anything to stderr. It produced frequent outputs to stdout, so I can determine what time it was interrupted by looking at its log.

I checked `dmesg` and `/var/log/syslog`, and there was nothing around the time it was interrupted.

On top of that, another process was also running on CUDA, in a different GPU, and continued running without issues.

This is not the first time it happens to me, and I still don't know how to determine what went wrong. Is there anything else I could check?

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 and CUDA 10.0, my processes are written in Python with pytorch.

Comment: Since we don't know your code, so key point is find a debug tool for CUDA program

Comment: I don't have an answer, but based on my own experiences seeing behavior like this, I wonder if it's an out-of-memory issue.  You say the other process was running on a different GPU, but...what if it wasn't actually?    Can you try repeating what you just did, only for a (much) smaller dataset, and see if the same crash occurs?

Comment: @sh37211 OOM errors leave a detailed output on stderr; I've had them a few times. I have also run the same code again, and now it finished without issues.